# Back button after the deeplink comes into the app does not go back to where it came from

Tags: android, browser, deep-linking

When there is a deeplink into the android app from the mobile browser website and then I press back button, the app shuts down and there is nothing in the background instead of going to the mobile browser website. I see the browser still in memory when I click the device button for all the open apps so I do not think browser is cleaned up by the OS. Has someone resolved this issue? Please help.

Comment: The device button doesn't show open apps it shows recent apps.  Many of them could have been removed by the OS.

Comment: ok got it but still it should go to the browser when I press back button immediately right? Is there something app can do to make it work.

Comment: Is it even possible that while launching the app from deeplink, something from the app is shutting down the browser. Someone please advice.

Comment: Can you add the AndroidManifest's part, where you specify deeplinking? (I checked on my app - after deep linking, once I click back - it goes back to the browser, as expected).

Comment: And also what is the API version you are testing against & device?

Comment: could you please add the manifest declaration of the launched activity?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following which might help you:

You can also redirect new users (who do not already have the app installed on their device) to download the app using a Attribution Analytics URL so we can attribute the installs generated from your website. We ensure that the loading of the Download URL (Attribution Analytics URL) is delayed by 1 second so that if the user does not have the app installed, then they will still view the bridge page and then be redirected to download the app from the app store after the Download URL loads.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour should be returning back to browser, actually. Does the issue happen for all devices and all Android API versions you tried?

Maybe, you do something wrong with in your `AndroidManifest`? Here's Activities' declaration I'm using and it works for me:

```
    <activity
        android:name="<activity_name>"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="<some_host>"
                android:pathPrefix="/<some_path_prefix>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: using android:launchMode="singleTask" not work for android 10 and above. when back press, it close the app.